# Dynamic Calculations with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I am building a custom online invoicing application and on the create invoices page, I have set it up so default it shows one row of items. But by clicking on the "New Row" button it adds rows to the table for more items. You can also delete rows if you change your mind.

Now, all the above is working just fine. I decided to take it one step further and automatically calculate totals for each line (line total) as well as the entire table (grand total). This is where I am having issues.

`Line Total:`

I have the following javascript for the line total:

```
function Calculate() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var price = $(par).find('input#price').val();
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var total = price*qty;
    $(par).find('input#total').val(total);
    CalculateTotal(total);
}
```

If `price` is `$12.95` and the `qty` is `2` the above script returns `25.9` I would like for it to return `$25.90` instead.

`Grand Total:` (Called from the above function automatically)

```
function CalculateTotal(rowTotal) {
    y = $("#Gtotal").text();
    z = rowTotal;
    x = +y + +z;
    $("#Gtotal").text(x);
}
```

Based on the examples above the above function would return `25.9` as well. I would also like for this to return `25.90` Also if I change the qty in the table to `0` the grand total does not change. But if I change the qty to `2` it returns `38.849999999999994` It has a ton more problems that I have found while testing with the table. That I won't list here.

So clearly you can see, I need a better way of handling the calculations in javascript. I'm not very experienced in javascript so any help would be really nice. I really need `dynamic calculations in javascript`

Since my code wouldn't copy here in a nice format. I created a jsFiddle to allow you to see my FULL code for the table as well as my javascript. [CLICK HERE TO SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vCs6E/4/)

Comment: you can use `.toFixed()`

Comment: you forgot to add jquery to your fiddle

Comment: Whoops... Check updated link in question.

Comment: Okay so `.toFixed(2)` fixed that issue. But the total doesn't follow the correct calculations if you change the qty after the initial set in any row.

Comment: You need an initial value in the Grand total text. See the fiddle in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parseFloat to convert the input values into floating points. And parseInt for integer conversions. Be sure to read the documentation how they work (parseInt especially, don't forget the second parameter to specify the radix).

See http://jsfiddle.net/vCs6E/6/ for a working fiddle.

Since SO requires the working code, here is the updated line in in Calculate()

`var total = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty);`

Comment: In your fiddle, the grand total doesn't appear to update correctly. Type in 1 for the qty and then type in 2. It doesn't match.

Comment: Indeed that is because the CalculateTotal() implementation is buggy. You are incrementing the grand total every time rather than adding up the individual line item totals...

Comment: I'm not very good at javascript, could you help me... What is a better way?

Comment: You've done a good job figuring out jQuery to do what you need so far. I encourage you to do the rest on your own General hints to get you on the right track: Every time the price or quantity text boxes change, update the Grand Total. So create jQuery event handlers on those input boxes (one way is to set your own css class for them).

Comment: More details: Use the on() method (https://api.jquery.com/on/) The event of course is "change". You can use "change" directly too (https://api.jquery.com/change/). Best.

Answer (score 0):

Using the checked answer AND this together:

```
var someNumber = 99.999923423;

// shows  99.99
console.log(someNumber.toFixed(2));
```

Will help.